# Get all Records between start date and end date [Asp.Net C# Web Forms]

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, webforms

I Have Table Named Employees_Attendance

```
{
Attend_ID  | EMPloyee_Name | Employee_Department | From_date  | To_date | Employee_ID

Employee_ID is Forigen_key To Employees Table Employee_ID Primary_Key
}
```

i am trying to fetch all records from Employees_attendance depends on $Start_date and $End_date
$Start_date is Text-Box Control Get his Text From Calendar Control
`{<asp:TextBox ID="TextFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> }`
And $End_date as Same as $Start_date

My Issue:
when i search by $Start_date and $end_date the Returned Record are Match the $start_date only.

My desired result:
I need To get all Records for Specific Employee Depends on the Date in Employees_attendance_tbl
Between $Start_date that got it from the Text-Box as i mentioned above
And $end_date That got it from Text box Too

Please Take a look at my Stored Procedure

```sql
{
USE [ASPCRUD]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DailyReportInfo]    Script Date: 11/23/2020 4:32:05 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[DailyReportInfo]

@Day_From  datetime,
@Day_To datetime
AS
BEGIN
select Emp_Attend.Emp_Name, Emp_Attend.Dep_Name , Emp_Attend.Day_From , Emp_Attend.Day_To  , Emp_Attend.Day_Type
from Emp_Attend 
LEFT JOIN Employees on Emp_Attend.Emp_ID = Employees.EmpID
WHERE
 CONVERT(date,Emp_Attend.Day_From) >= CONVERT(date,@Day_From) AND  CONVERT(date,Emp_Attend.Day_From) <= CONVERT(date,@Day_From) OR
 
 CONVERT(date,Emp_Attend.Day_To) >= CONVERT(date,@Day_To) AND  CONVERT(date,Emp_Attend.Day_To) <= CONVERT(date,@Day_To)
END
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting `Emp_Attend.Day_From` and `Emp_Attend.Day_To` to a `date`? Are they a `varchar`?

Comment: cuz I insert the start_date and end_date in employee_attend tbl datetime

Comment: and i want to search by date only so i convert it !!

Comment: But both `2020-01-01` and `2020-01-01T17:00:00` are **after** `2020-12-31`. Converting just slows the query down.

Comment: Have a read of [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/140734)

Comment: what is issue in my query

Comment: why it return only date depends on start_date not all records between start date and end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you want ANY attendance date between the given start/end date.

this is simple.

A collision occurs based on this logic:

```
RequestStartDate <= EndDate 
and 
RequestEndDate >= StartDate
```

The above will find ALL AND ANY overlaps.

So if the attendance record brackets the start end (is earlier and later), then a match occurs.

And if any request date falls in the range, then again a match occurs.

And if any request date overlaps? Then again a match occurs with the above SIMPLE condition.

so, lets build a form.

Drop in label + text box. Set text box format as date.
Cut + paste (start + end)

Drag gridview on form. So far? Less then 2 minutes time spend here.

So, we have this:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="End Date" Style="margin-left:20px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRequestEnd" runat="server" Style="margin-left:20px" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Style="margin-left:20px"/>
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

[image]

So, to fill a grid with the results of the stored procedure we can use this code behind the button:

```
  Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("GetBookings",
                                   New SqlConnection(GetConstr()))
        cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ReqStart", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtRequestStart.Text
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ReqEnd", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtRequestEnd.Text

        Dim rs As New DataTable
        rs.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        GridView1.DataSource = rs
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using
```

And the results are this:

[image]

My stored procedure is this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBookings]
    @ReqStart datetime,
    @ReqEnd datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM vBooking 
    WHERE @ReqStart <= ToDate 
      AND @ReqEnd >= FromDate
      AND HotelName IS NOT NULL
END
```

So, in your case, just use the above simple collision logic. Any overlap, for the start, or the end, or even a range that falls inside of your Request start + end will work for the above.